# Is it possible to run wcript.exe in elevated mode when doubleclicked in Windows explorer?

Tags: vbscript, scripting, windows-10, uac, elevation

I currently have a huge number of VBS Scripts which are, when doubleclicked in Windows Explorer, run by wscript.exe. These scripts need to be run in UAC elevated mode, i.e. doubleclicking by default will not work.

One solution for this would be to alter all the scripts, and make the scripts run themselves elevated, this solution can be found on many places, but Altering all the scripts is a tedious work.

So I am currently thinking of another solution to alter the default Shell Extension behaviour in Windows 10, so that wscript.exe will always be started elevated wenn a vbs script is doubleclicked in Windows Explorer. The problem is that I currently cannot find any commandline option that I can pass to wscript.exe to run it elevated.

Is there any solution available to call wscript.exe always in elevated mode? The scenario that should work is that a user can doubleclick the .vbs-file in Windows Explorer, and then automatically be prompted with the UAC-elevation dialog (if configured in Windows)

Comment: Make a shortcut to it and set the shortcut to run elevated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Task Scheduler to run your script as an administrator without having to go through User Account Control (UAC) every time.

You can run scripts as administrator with the runas verb, but the user must have admin rights on the machine to do so.

You could store admin credentials in the script, but it would be plain text and not secure.

Run elevated commands  only work on machines where you have local admin privileges. Other non admins can't use the script.

Comment: This is not the solution I am looking for, because a user of my system should be able to run the script in explorer by simply doubleclicking it.